# Converting itsdangerous python code to javascript using itsdangerous port

Tags: itsdangerous

I am trying to convert the following python code to Typescript:

```
import sys
import json

def encode_flask_cookie(secret_key, cookie_dict):
     import hashlib
     from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer
     from flask.sessions import TaggedJSONSerializer
     salt = 'cookie-session'
     serializer = TaggedJSONSerializer()
     signer_kwargs = {
         'key_derivation': 'hmac',
         'digest_method': hashlib.sha1
     }
     s = URLSafeTimedSerializer(secret_key, salt=salt, serializer=serializer, signer_kwargs=signer_kwargs)
     return s.dumps(cookie_dict)

sys.stdout.write(encode_flask_cookie(sys.argv[1], json.loads(sys.argv[2])))
```

I think I am fairly close with:

```
  async getFlaskSessionToken(data: JsonObject): Promise<string> {
    const itsdanger = await (eval('import("itsdangerous.js")') as Promise<
      typeof import('itsdangerous.js')
    >);

    const authSerializer = new itsdanger.URLSafeTimedSerializer({
      secretKey: process.env.FLASK_SECRET_KEY as string,
      salt: 'cookie-session',
      signerOpts: {
        keyDerivation: itsdanger.KeyDerivation.Hmac,
        digestMethod: 'sha1'
      }
    } );
    const token = authSerializer.stringify(data);
    const returnData = token.toString();

    //console.log(returnData)
    return returnData;
  }
```

However, I get back slightly different results and was hoping someone could shed light on it maybe:

python:

```
.eJwVlMeyg8oBRP_lrs0tGIKEV0ZIBJGTCBuKIQ45iuDyv_u-ZZ9enFX3f3-Sba3wOEnTfFnidWjy_uffP_n5rqCYIgO9mySQkcq_W9hp_-SHVnvAxnVdRjtKAv2S6wElko2nksaoJ1tlgT1EPo0nvl5lorem_msLu8-ViSypdvoXOndUWL-_kyeAYn_dThbFhewJvwxHuYzGl3U8yphkvjr56p4RUSNBqzpOs0X0CbZ5L6L5EeQj9pxnV52CyMLLlNdRZ5kS80Xs8Bkk6enqen-3jZNvapE_C6x6Ta0Sp_3OmxT-1jyWlZ8dZ4Wdje26HuEc_dFijZJmH_KuCbbhyBWMOjZuQyxZKGONkcwqyU5HqmYvlqZAJelkVHOZrm9NzCyDsfOZgRW2P4UhnAXuDCnvyoTGS1NP2Naa4BI5Pgh7m-BloS4Sg53iG4ajzT1-BOVyayLNjuU5N0q6sgDB0IJ7lZx_sP15Luu2vp--SaoJTdz4wyn5TSpsM3D2j57WyfjCGMKlbOV5ahFoDAxoVs6AMrtZddOyRnV3W-1ItqV09I7FJREFGS3kkf3AZ4uNIwA4wFfNuX5fCStAb9Wzsa-QPsufzQJcndzEInBDXtnWab540YvVRyhkPscqd_yA-0K5o227FH4rEJmrr7rFzZ2zjE3Uw9aA33RHUZ0MwnZttxPIVf1ATATMetdJvxo_r-ROLEB_uE4aCeI0UtvqVoW0ZtogPsdPK8Pn0p85XXYsc_TxRy3EM5zgVFxwb6CTvVOTA5zXXRN833LUKeSmvfJRrkZS4Q5-d7083vVJA9iD5_GAsSJaIQt5vcE6sWBMCaTo23j1ZvnwTjn3dlgv-XbQxT4wrZ-ItQ5morzvznfHl1niQt6xqKnWv_O04s6e4dpdXt6AV3V14MWrPdimAZNF7c3mh-_MCGJ_ewWjltVeT3oDEYNiKXVdK5vYLAn42JWv9X6yu319_zbjqXbrUekVCGpMHQc2c2bOrlB5VTYemvM6rpFiGM1gEECit-Frz-A46fgbY14FFERUSY9PYbYGJoHt-5_tG-s5vYJBRnKDnO6uyNPEuCy6kGDBwoSzrvVpLEykBqFtOooBKk9aiIiefDyPPpEOyr6O854jB7UN_LtToXZ_XNeaXqjb6jeZdzVm6K55kdwr2Po54w3v7kv6n_gICqkKCRh-l94zY8TUU_pZRJYNG9CzY4vjo5wccIbKOJFnOn-P_iaHHxQ9CPpqbadtPX8MwBktXKUSPOnFZPPbvKtnJtvxXU_pRPBji2bp5_7zr5-8S1D7z3td_4H5sg77bzp0f3xb8jlG2V8DSXAvmJzGmIRNMCrPIQYp8oYRaZJSJJ6nFEX__O__fE63Dw.ZSRbJg._TY2_YuBkWIlWMxD8tlC_LCPBtc
```

Javascript:

```
.eJwVlMeyg8oBRP_lrs0tGIKEV0ZIBJGTCBuKIQ45iuDyv_u-ZZ9enFX3f3-Sba3wOEnTfFnidWjy_uffP_n5rqCYIgO9mySQkcq_W9hp_-SHVnvAxnVdRjtKAv2S6wElko2nksaoJ1tlgT1EPo0nvl5lorem_msLu8-ViSypdvoXOndUWL-_kyeAYn_dThbFhewJvwxHuYzGl3U8yphkvjr56p4RUSNBqzpOs0X0CbZ5L6L5EeQj9pxnV52CyMLLlNdRZ5kS80Xs8Bkk6enqen-3jZNvapE_C6x6Ta0Sp_3OmxT-1jyWlZ8dZ4Wdje26HuEc_dFijZJmH_KuCbbhyBWMOjZuQyxZKGONkcwqyU5HqmYvlqZAJelkVHOZrm9NzCyDsfOZgRW2P4UhnAXuDCnvyoTGS1NP2Naa4BI5Pgh7m-BloS4Sg53iG4ajzT1-BOVyayLNjuU5N0q6sgDB0IJ7lZx_sP15Luu2vp--SaoJTdz4wyn5TSpsM3D2j57WyfjCGMKlbOV5ahFoDAxoVs6AMrtZddOyRnV3W-1ItqV09I7FJREFGS3kkf3AZ4uNIwA4wFfNuX5fCStAb9Wzsa-QPsufzQJcndzEInBDXtnWab540YvVRyhkPscqd_yA-0K5o227FH4rEJmrr7rFzZ2zjE3Uw9aA33RHUZ0MwnZttxPIVf1ATATMetdJvxo_r-ROLEB_uE4aCeI0UtvqVoW0ZtogPsdPK8Pn0p85XXYsc_TxRy3EM5zgVFxwb6CTvVOTA5zXXRN833LUKeSmvfJRrkZS4Q5-d7083vVJA9iD5_GAsSJaIQt5vcE6sWBMCaTo23j1ZvnwTjn3dlgv-XbQxT4wrZ-ItQ5morzvznfHl1niQt6xqKnWv_O04s6e4dpdXt6AV3V14MWrPdimAZNF7c3mh-_MCGJ_ewWjltVeT3oDEYNiKXVdK5vYLAn42JWv9X6yu319_zbjqXbrUekVCGpMHQc2c2bOrlB5VTYemvM6rpFiGM1gEECit-Frz-A46fgbY14FFERUSY9PYbYGJoHt-5_tG-s5vYJBRnKDnO6uyNPEuCy6kGDBwoSzrvVpLEykBqFtOooBKk9aiIiefDyPPpEOyr6O854jB7UN_LtToXZ_XNeaXqjb6jeZdzVm6K55kdwr2Po54w3v7kv6n_gICqkKCRh-l94zY8TUU_pZRJYNG9CzY4vjo5wccIbKOJFnOn-P_iaHHxQ9CPpqbadtPX8MwBktXKUSPOnFZPPbvKtnJtvxXU_pRPBji2bp5_7zr5-8S1D7z3td_4H5sg77bzp0f3xb8jlG2V8DSXAvmJzGmIRNMCrPIQYp8oYRaZJSJJ6nFEX__O__fE63Dw.MTY5Njg4MTQ0Ng.XOe-8kHBBujKVvaooEV4KEkqa5U
```

Is it correct to say that only the signature is different?  Any thoughts on if this can be fixed?

I am using
"itsdangerous.js": "1.0.0"
in my Typescript project and python 3.10.6

I think its the timstamp produced by the itsdangerous port that is the issue.  Its longer and its included in the signature.  Not sure what is different about it, though ( I think the timstamp is the second to last part, delimited by period)

If anyone has ideas regarding converting the Python code to Javascript without using an itsdangerous port, I'd be interested.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is the timestamp.  Here is a sample of a timestamp call that maps to the python version.

```
 getTimestamp() {
        
        const time = Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
        const timeBuffer = Buffer.alloc(8);
        timeBuffer.writeBigUInt64BE(BigInt(time), 0);
        const timeBytes = timeBuffer.slice(timeBuffer.findIndex(b => b !== 0));
        const base64Url = base64url.encode(timeBytes).replace(/=+$/, '');
        console.log(`base64Url = ${base64Url}`);
        return base64Url;
    }
```

I am going to fork https://github.com/hampuskraft/itsdangerous.js and add it in for my use.